# WPF Control Template Trigger Assigned to Container

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've defined a control template for my top level items of a menu as follows:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.TopLevelItemTemplateKey}" TargetType="MenuItem">
   <Border x:Name="Border">
      <Grid x:Name="Grid" >
         <ContentPresenter 
            ContentSource="Header"  
            RecognizesAccessKey="False"  
            Margin="10,5,50,5" 
            TextBlock.FontFamily="Segoe UI" 
            TextBlock.FontSize="14" 
            TextBlock.Foreground="White"/>
      </Grid>
   </Border>
   <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
         <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ControlMouseOver}"/>
      </Trigger>
   </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

This is giving me the style I want, however the trigger is only triggered when I hover over the text of the menu. Ideally i want the item to become highlighted when I hover over its parent grid element. Tried changing the trigger to this

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
   <Trigger Property="Grid.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
      <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ControlMouseOver}"/>
   </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

but doesn't work. Any suggestions as to where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make whole `Border` (or `Grid`) hit test visible you need to initialize `Background` property with some `Brush`. You can set it to `Transparent` for example

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.TopLevelItemTemplateKey}" TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Border x:Name="Border" Background="Transparent" >
        <!-- -->
    </Border>
    <!-- -->
</ControlTemplate>
```